# invoke make from build

Tags: gcc, build, makefile

I'd like to simplify the workflow so that rather than issuing these commands

```
$ make program_unittest
  ... output of $MAKE ...
$ ./program_unittest args
```

I could have my program automatically attempt to compile itself (if the source has been updated) when it is run, so that I do not have to go back and run make myself.

Here's what I'm thinking: My unit test build should first check if there is a makefile in the directory it's in, and if so, fork and exec `make` with the target corresponding to itself. If `make` determines "nothing to be done", it will continue on its way (running the unit-tests). However, if `make` actually performs a compilation, one of two things may happen. `gcc` (invoked by `make`) might be able to overwrite the build (an older version of which is already running) during compilation, in which case I can then perhaps exec it. If my system does not permit `gcc` to overwrite the program which is in use, then I have to quit the program before running `make`.

So this has become quite involved already. Are there perhaps more elegant solutions? Maybe I could use a bash script? How do I ascertain if `make` issued compilation commands or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not have make run the unit tests?